# PYTHON - Como criar uma lista contendo cada elemento de uma lista anterior, dentro de outra lista

Tags: python, lista

Acho que o jeito mais fácil de descrever o problema é mostrando o objetivo, senão fica confuso.

Preciso transformar algo assim:
`[['3 -1 2 0 2 0 -1 -1', '4 2 4 5 1 0 0 1 1'], ['6 -8 -8 15 15 0', '5 -1 3 2']]`

Em algo assim:
`[[['3 -1 2 0 2 0 -1 -1'], ['4 2 4 5 1 0 0 1 1']], [['6 -8 -8 15 15 0'], ['5 -1 3 2']]]`

A ideia parece simples, mas não tô conseguindo separar isso nunca, sem perder a separação que tá no primeiro exemplo. É imperativo que eu tenha essa separação em 3 níveis (pq depois ainda tenho q separar os valores dentro de cada lista)

Comment: Supondo que `l` seja a lista acima, faça `[[[s[0]],[s[1]]] for s in l]` teste o exemplo: https://ideone.com/469ATT

Answer (score -1, accepted):

bom escrevir um codigo bem rapido aqui de acordo com que você queria, espero ter ajudando

```
arrays = [['3 -1 2 0 2 0 -1 -1', '4 2 4 5 1 0 0 1 1'], ['6 -8 -8 15 15 0', '5 -1 3 2']]

newArrays = list()
temp = list()

for array in arrays:
    for item in array:
        temp.append([item])

    newArrays.append(temp.copy())
    temp.clear()
    
print(newArrays)
```